# jquery on event for a dynamically generated child of a dynamically generated child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, mouseenter

I have a div that gets added to dynamically and I would like to have a mouseenter event for images that have been dynamically added in another tag. The div that is getting added to looks like this before hand:

```
<div class="chat_box">

</div>
```

and looks like this after content has been added:

```
<div class="chat_box">
  <p class="chat">text here <img class="emote" src="emote.png"> more text</p>
</div>
```

I would like to have a mouseenter event for the image with the class of emote, but I cannot get it to work.

I have tried the following:

```
$('.chat_box').on('mouseenter', '.chat', function(){
  alert();
});
```

and it works, but if I try to use the child selector

```
$('.chat_box').on('mouseenter', '.chat > .emote', function(){
  alert();
});
```

and

```
$('.chat_box').on('mouseenter', '.chat > img', function(){
  alert();
});
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: Check your selector your selecting `chat_box` but you dont define your class try `$('.chat_box')`

Comment: @HakanKose Sorry that was a typo.  I have it like that in my actual code.

Comment: Can't reproduce it: https://jsfiddle.net/946j9vqh/ Problem is somewhere else, obviously.

Comment: I am running it on node.  Would that affect it?

Answer (score 0):

This was previously provided by .live(), but that function has been merged into .on() ... it creates an event watcher.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="chat_box"></div>

<button>Add</button>

<script>
$('button').click(function(){
    $('<div class="chat"><img width=10 height=10 class="emote"></div>').appendTo('.chat_box');
});
$('.chat_box').on('mouseenter', 'img.emote', function(){ alert('test'); });           
</script>
```

Just target the parent object and have it watch for the expected child.

Comment: This isn't working.  I tried it before and I thought it didn't work because the on event could only effect direct children.  Either way, it doesn't work sadly

Comment: What is posted above is tested and works for me. I tried it again to make sure there were no copy/paste errors.

Is there anything strange about your test environment?

Comment: it's running on node.js with socket.io, but the actual jquery that would be affecting the image is client side of course.  I don't know, would node mess it up or something? @sorak

Comment: Can you test just my clip of code and see if that does what you need? If so, I would be willing to look at where you're trying to integrate it and make it work.

Comment: well, its working now.  I changed some stuff around in the css for the parent and I think that's what did it though I don't know why so I kinda expect it to break again.  If it does I'll let you now. Thanks

Comment: If I helped you, please consider accepting my answer. Happy holidays!